# Head commit for all remote branches using Git

Tags: git, commit, remote-branch

I know how to list the remote branches

```
$ git branch -a
```

And I know how to find the head commit hash of my current branch

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
```

But I'm not sure how to list all the head commit hashes for all the remote branches.  This is close to what I want but what order are they in?

```
$ git rev-parse --remotes
4b9f7128e9e7fa7d72652ba49c90c37d0727123d
4ebab9616fac6896b7827e8502b4dc7c5aac6b5b
ea7a5fab4a757fb0826253acf1fe7d8c546c178e
...
```

Ideally, I'd like a list of branch-name commit-hash pairs or even a way to pass a remote branch name to `git rev-parse HEAD`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use either

```
git branch -r -v --no-abbrev
```

and ignore part with commit message or

```
git show-ref
```

and filter results starting with refs/remotes.

Comment: Somewhat related; `git show-ref` gives you hashes for tags too. Know that these are the *hashes of the tags* themselves and *not the commits they point to*.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is old and answered, but I think `git ls-remote` would work for this too.

```
git ls-remote --heads origin

fcce961b46784fae13be8a30c2622ddd34d970ec        refs/heads/develop
9da7bb692a72235451706f24790a3f7a100a64e2        refs/heads/feature-netty-testing
86020c50d86691caecff4a55d3b1f2f588f6291d        refs/heads/javafx-testing
871d715e5c072b1fbfacecc986f678214fa0b585        refs/heads/master
7ed641c96d910542edeced5fc470d63b8b4734f0        refs/heads/orphan-branch
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git rev-parse` for this. It can take anything which looks even remotely like a commit and returns the full SHA1 hash for that commit.

For example, to get the SHA1 of `HEAD`:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

To get the SHA1 of `master`:

```
git rev-parse master
```

To get the SHA1 of `origin/trunk`:

```
git rev-parse origin/trunk
```

To get the SHA1s of all remote heads (this is just one of many ways to do this, and *certainly* not the best one):

```
 git branch -r | cut -d' ' -f 3 | while read remote; do
   echo ${remote} `git rev-parse ${remote}`
done
```